# Add rule to generate specific headers if missing

Tags: makefile, java-native-interface

I have a Makefile that mixes Java and C++ with JNI and I would like to generate the JNI header automatically when needed.

Currently, I have the following:

```
$(OBJDIR)/org_some_package_%.cpp: $(INCDIR)/jni/org_some_package_%.h

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) \
        -I$(INCDIR) -I../build/include -I"$(JAVA_HOME)/include" -I"$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux" \
        -MD -MF $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $@) $<

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(INCDIR)/jni/%.h: $(JAVA_TEST_BIN)/$$(subst _,/,%).class
    @mkdir -p $(INCDIR)/jni
    $(JAVAH) -d inc/jni -classpath TestJNI/bin/tests:$(JUNIT_JAR):$(HAMCREST_JAR) $(basename $(subst _,.,$(subst $(INCDIR)/jni/,,$@)))
```

The problem is that when a `.o` file is needed, the first rule is never applied:

```
$(OBJDIR)/org_some_package_%.cpp: $(INCDIR)/jni/org_some_package_%.h
```

If I replace this rule with a specific one (by replacing `%` by the name of a class), it works.

How can I make this generic rule work?

---

I don't want to do this:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(INCDIR)/jni/%.h
```

...because I may have `.cpp` files that do not correspond to JNI header.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create simple prerequisites using patterns.  A pattern rule without any recipe doesn't define a prerequisite, it cancels a previously-existing pattern rule.  The [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) says:

> You can cancel a built-in implicit rule by defining a pattern rule with the same target and prerequisites, but no recipe.

The only way to create a prerequisite is to make it explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I didn't know this rule... I'll have to find a different way to generate these headers.

Answer (score 1):

So, your `$(INCDIR)/jni/a_b_c.h` depend on `$(JAVA_TEST_BIN)/a/b/c.class`? You will have to use advanced make features. I assume that all `*.class` file under `$(JAVA_TEST_BIN)` correspond to a built header file. This (not tested) should do what you show in your question:

```
CLASSES := $(patsubst $(JAVA_TEST_BIN)/%.class,%,$(shell find $(JAVA_TEST_BIN) -type f -name '*.class'))

BUILT_HEADERS :=

# $(1): class
define BUILD_HEADER_rule
header := $$(INCDIR)/jni/$$(subst /,_,$(1)).h

$$(header): $$(JAVA_TEST_BIN)/$(1).class

BUILT_HEADERS += $$(header)
endef
$(foreach c,$(CLASSES),$(eval $(call BUILD_HEADER_rule,$(c))))

$(BUILT_HEADERS):
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(JAVAH) -d inc/jni -classpath TestJNI/bin/tests:$(JUNIT_JAR):$(HAMCREST_JAR) $(basename $(subst _,.,$(subst $(INCDIR)/jni/,,$@)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't think this can work because the `.class` files are generated by another rule... I will see if I can adapt your code to my actual problem.

Comment: Also, for clarification, I am substituing `_` by `/` and `.` because with JNI, the class name (with packages) is something like `org.package.MyClass`, the folder structure is `org/package/MyClass` and the header filename is `org_package_MyClass`.

Comment: @Holt: "_the folder structure is `org/package/MyClass` and the header filename is `org_package_MyClass`_" I see, I edited my answer to remove this note.

Comment: @Holt: "_the .class files are generated by another rule_" if they are generated each from one specific source file, then you can adapt the same technique to generate the `.class` and `.h` rules. If they are all generated by one single rule, you can probably solve your problem with one single recursive call to make.